# formset_factory and updating a field to show only filtered items

Tags: django, django-forms

On my scorecard entry form, i only want the user to select from the shortlisted players for that match. If there was one field, I am succesfully able to rewrite using.

```
form.fields['player'].queryset = PlayerShortlist.objects.filter(team=userteam, fixture=fixture_id)
```

but when i apply it on formset_factory, i am unable to get result.

my forms.py

```
class TossForm(forms.Form):
    toss_won_by = forms.BooleanField()
    bat_first = forms.BooleanField()

class InningsForm(forms.Form):
    player = forms.ModelChoiceField(
        PlayerShortlist.objects.all()
    )
    status = forms.ChoiceField(choices=OUT_CHOICES, initial='DNB')
    score = forms.IntegerField(initial=0)
    balls_faced = forms.IntegerField(initial=0)
```

my views.py

```
@login_required
def scorecard(request, team_id, fixture_id):
    template = get_template('cricket/scorecard.html')
    tossform = TossForm()
    #inningform = InningsForm()
    InningsForms = formset_factory(InningsForm, extra=11)
    inningsforms = InningsForm()
    inningsforms.fields['player'].queryset = PlayerShortlist.objects.filter(team=Team.objects.get(id=1), fixture=fixture_id)

    page_vars = Context({
        'loggedinuser': request.user,
        'tossform': tossform,
        'inningsforms': inningsforms,
    })
    crsfcontext = RequestContext(request, page_vars)
    output = template.render(crsfcontext)
    return HttpResponse(output)
```

it gives me errors.

'InningsFormFormSet' object has no attribute 'fields'

thanks

//yousuf

okey, i looked around, and it seems formfield_callback can be used for what i intend it for but when i use it lin my views.py like

```
def update_field(field, **kwargs):
        if field.name == 'players':
            field.queryset = PlayerShortlist.objects.filter(team=Team.objects.get(id=team_id), fixture=fixture_id)

    InningsFormset = formset_factory(InningsForm, extra=11, formfield_callback)
```

it gives me

**formset_factory() got an unexpected keyword argument 'formfield_callback'**

Answer (score 1):

Remember: a formset wraps around a list of forms. So this:

```
inningsforms.fields['player'].queryset = PlayerShortlist.objects.filter(team=Team.objects.get(id=1), fixture=fixture_id)
```

Should rather be:

```
qs = PlayerShortlist.objects.filter(team=Team.objects.get(id=1), fixture=fixture_id)

# force execution of the queryset once and for all
list(qs)

for form in inningsforms.forms:
    form.fields['player'].queryset = qs
```

Also, formfield_callback is an argument of modelformset_factory (and modelform_factory), not of formset_factory. See how it is used:

```
def modelformset_factory(model, form=ModelForm, formfield_callback=None,
                         formset=BaseModelFormSet,
                         extra=1, can_delete=False, can_order=False,
                         max_num=None, fields=None, exclude=None):
    """  
    Returns a FormSet class for the given Django model class.
    """
    form = modelform_factory(model, form=form, fields=fields, exclude=exclude,
                             formfield_callback=formfield_callback)
    FormSet = formset_factory(form, formset, extra=extra, max_num=max_num,
                              can_order=can_order, can_delete=can_delete)
    FormSet.model = model
    return FormSet
```

See, formfield_callback is proxied to modelform_factory by modelformset_factory.